# How to ask Scapy to send packets faster, say 1000pps

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, packet, flooding

I just wanna control the velocity of packet generation, because Scapy is too slow to send packets by default using "send". Some suggestions say "sendpfast" can specify PPS, however, it doesn't work in my script, neither does "sendp". After replace "send" with "sendp"/"sendpfast", I noticed that there was nothing on Wireshark, the packets were not sent. what am I missing?

Comment: You could use multiprocessing or threading to speed it up.

Comment: @jfleach could you please give me an example how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sendpfast()` and add the second layer to your packets.
This would mean simply adding

```
Ether()/...
```

Before each packet.